# Calculate average of each column in a file

Tags: awk, average, delimiter

I have a text file with n number of rows (separated by commas) and columns and I want to find average of each column, excluding empty field.

A sample input looks like:

```
1,2,3
4,,6
,7,
```

The desired output is:

```
2.5, 4.5, 4.5
```

I tried with

```
awk -F',' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]=sum[i]+$i;if(max < NF)max=NF;};END { for(j=1;j<=max;j++) printf "%d\t",sum[j]/max;}' input
```

But it treats consecutive delimiters as one and mixing columns. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First field average should probably be 2.5?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this one-liner:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[i]+=$i; if($i!="") b[i]++}}; END {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", a[i]/b[i], (i==NF?ORS:OFS)}' foo
2.5 4.5 4.5
```

Otherwise, you can save this in a file `script.awk` and run `awk -f script.awk your_file`:

```
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[i]+=$i
        if($i!="") 
            b[i]++}
    } 
END {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        printf "%s%s", a[i]/b[i], (i==NF?ORS:OFS)
}
```